Import Wrapped Key to Keystore
I generate the RSA key pair and the aes key, then wrap the aes key using the rsa public key.Then  try to import the encrypted AES key to Android Keystore but a meaningless error message appears
That line generating the error :
keyStore.setEntry(IMPORTED_KEY_ALIAS, wrappedKeyEntry, null);?

Error message:
:java.security.KeyStoreException: Failed to import wrapped key. Keystore error code: -1000  
at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreSpi.setWrappedKeyEntry(AndroidKeyStoreSpi.java:983)

I can see that the wrapped key is created correctly by debugging.
private KeyPair getOrCreateKeyPair() throws Exception {
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    keyStore.load(null);
    if (!keyStore.containsAlias(KEY_ALIAS)) {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(
                new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_ALIAS,
                        KeyProperties.PURPOSE_WRAP_KEY | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                        .setKeySize(2048)
                        .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_OAEP)
                        .build());
        return keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    } else {
        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(KEY_ALIAS, null);
        return new KeyPair(privateKeyEntry.getCertificate().getPublicKey(), privateKeyEntry.getPrivateKey());
    }
}

private SecretKey generateAESKey() throws Exception {
    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    keyGenerator.init(256);
    return keyGenerator.generateKey();
}
private byte[] wrapKey(PublicKey publicKey, SecretKey aesKey) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding", "BC");
    cipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, publicKey);
    return cipher.wrap(aesKey);
}

private void importWrappedKey(byte[] wrappedKey) throws Exception {
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    keyStore.load(null, null);

    AlgorithmParameterSpec spec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(IMPORTED_KEY_ALIAS,
            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_WRAP_KEY )
            .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
            .build();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        WrappedKeyEntry wrappedKeyEntry = new WrappedKeyEntry(wrappedKey, KEY_ALIAS, "RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding", spec);
        keyStore.setEntry(IMPORTED_KEY_ALIAS, wrappedKeyEntry, null);
    }
}

